Is it safe to open File Explorer after my Microsoft School account was deleted on Windows 11?
About less than a month ago, my Microsoft School account was deleted, and now I’m afraid to open File Explorer.
I suspect that there might be synced files or cached data from my school’s OneDrive still on my machine. I’m worried that opening File Explorer might accidentally trigger some kind of deletion or overwrite of those files, and I don’t want to risk losing anything important.
Here's my system information:

Device name: MSI
Processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H 2.70 GHz
Installed RAM: 8.00 GB (7.71 GB usable)
System type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
Edition: Windows 11 Home Single Language
Version: 23H2
Installed on: 07-10-2022
OS build: 22631.4169
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1034.0

Has anyone dealt with something like this? What’s the safest way to access my files without risking data loss or sync errors? Should I disable OneDrive or take any other precautions first?

Perhaps if you disconnect the computer from the internet, then log in and open the file explorer and copy the relevant files to a non-sync'd location?

To be safe, disconnect from internet, boot the PC from rescue media n(e.g., https://www.hirensbootcd.org or  https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) and make a full drive image. Then nothing will be lost. https://writersalmanac.publicradio.org/index.php%3Fdate=2014%252F02%252F08.html

If there isn’t an account then there isn’t anything to synchronize to, OneDrive, isn’t going to delete local files. Besides OneDrive doesn’t require you to open File Explorer to synchronize files. If this were to happen it would have happened a month ago when the account was deleted

File explorer is just a visual element to a process always running on your computer. Opening it will not do anything. You should probably speak with your School regarding your possible data loss situation.

Do you mean the school account was deleted, and you can no longer log in to it, but you don't want to lose the files you had on OneDrive using this account? If so, you need to disconnect the Internet, then copy these files out of local OneDrive folder.

File Explorer is just a visual element to an application that is always running on a Windows computer. Also, OneDrive syncs its files and performs directed actions whenever you're sign in to the computer, whether or not File Explorer is open.
Any actions that would have happened already did, and opening File Explorer will not make anything that might happen, happen.
If you are concerned about data loss in your school account, you should talk with your school. Any data in the cloud will be retained per their defined retention rules and settings.
On your computer, just open File Explorer and look for the files. I'm guessing your school gave you instructions before you left regarding actions you should take on the data to preserve it on your own, once your school account was inactivated.

Thanks for the clarification! Just one thing — I’m concerned that there could still be cached OneDrive files from my school account on the system. Would those be at risk if I open File Explorer, or are cached files unaffected by this process?

That is the same answer: opening the File Explorer does not impact your files at all. The applications that deal with the cached files are not triggered by opening the visible File Explorer windows.

Thanks for the clarification! That puts my mind at ease about opening File Explorer. One more question: Could opening File Explorer cause any loss of cached previews of files? I’m specifically wondering if file thumbnails or previews tied to OneDrive would disappear or refresh, making it harder to recognize the files I had previously accessed.
